# On the determinant of a Kronecker power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, kronecker-product

Let

$$ Y := \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right)^{\otimes k} $$

where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). We have

$$ \det(Y) = \left(\sqrt{2^k}\right)^{2^k} = 2^{k2^{k-1}} $$

I know how to derive the result by induction, but I have no idea why the first equation is true.

Comment: You can check the formula of the determinant of Kronecker products. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations

Comment: I think you can go directly to the answer. Suggestion diagonalise $\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$, and count how often $(1+i), (1-i)$ appear in the product of the eigenvalues of $Y$.  But this does not answer your question.

Comment: Use the following three facts:

1) How determinant of a block matrix is calculated.
2) How Kronecker product of matrices looks.
3) What happens to the determinant of a matrix, if you multiply each row or each column by the same number.

From these three facts, one can easily obtain the general formula $\det{A\otimes B}=(\det{A})^{m} \cdot (\det{B})^{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are dimensions of the square matrices $A, B$.

Answer (score 2):

Just getting this off the unanswered list.

In general, if $A_i$ is an $n_i\times n_i$ matrix for $i=1,\ldots,k$, then

$$\det \left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^k A_i \right) = \prod_{i=1}^k \det(A_i)^{n_1\cdots n_k/n_i}\tag{1}$$
This can be proved by induction on $k$, where for $k=2$ we can use methods suggested in the comments.

Taking $A_i=A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ for all $i$ in (1), we obtain

$$\det(A^{\otimes k})=\prod_{i=1}^k 2^{2^k/2}=\left(2^{2^{k-1}}\right)^k=2^{k2^{k-1}}\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an answer which may explain where the "first equation" comes from.

Note that

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}=
\sqrt{2}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 0\\0 &\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $1$, and therefore its tensor powers $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}^{\otimes k}$ also have determinant $1$.

The determinant of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}^{\otimes k}$ is therefore equal to the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 0\\0 &\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}^{\otimes k}$. This latter matrix is a diagonal $2^k \times 2^k$ matrix each of whose entries is $\sqrt{2}\,^k$. Hence the required determinant is $(\sqrt{2}\,^k)^{2^k}$.

I agree that this is not $(\sqrt{2^k)}^{2^k}$; I don't think there's a natural direct way to see that this is true.